# Specific application of the while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I wonder if you could help me with this practical exercise:

Make a Program that asks for the 2 grades of 2 students, calculate and store the average of each student in a list, print the number of students with an average greater than or equal to 7.0.

I managed to do it using the for loop, but I would like to use the while loop. I'm trying this code, but the list of averages is not coming out correctly. I appreciate any help.

```
notesStudents = []
listNotes = []
student = 1
notes = 1
average = 0
while student <= 2:
    while notes <= 2:  
        notesStudents.append(float(input(f"What is the {notes}ª grade of the Student {student}?")))
        notes += 1
    notes = 1
    student += 1
    average += notesStudents[notes]
    average = average / 3
    listNotes.append(average)
print(listNotes)
```

Comment: What's `media`?

Comment: Sorry, I did the editing.

Answer (score 0):

The `notes` and `studentNotes` variables should be re-initialized within the loop, otherwise you just keep appending to the same list of `studentNotes`. Also, right now you just set `average` to the `studentNodes[1] / 3`, which is not correct. You should get the sum of all the notes and divide them by the proper number.

```
listNotes = []
student = 1
while student <= 2:
    notes = 1
    notesStudents = []
    while notes <= 2:  
        notesStudents.append(float(input(f"What is the {notes}ª grade of the Student {student}?")))
        notes += 1
    average = sum(notesStudents) / len(notesStudents)
    listNotes.append(average)
    student += 1
print(listNotes)
```

This would however be much simpler and less verbose with `for` loops and maybe even a list comprehension:

```
listNotes = []
for student in range(1, 3):
    notesStudents = [float(input(f"What is the {n}ª grade of the Student {student}? "))
                     for n in range(1, 3)]
    average = sum(notesStudents) / len(notesStudents)
    listNotes.append(average)
print(listNotes)
```